# How to get information about a function and call it

Tags: python

I want to make a function that detects if a method exists for given instance, what are the parameters that can be passed in and then call the method with proper parameters. I am novice and I have no idea how to do it :(

Comment: Do you know the method name at the time that you check for existence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `hasattr`

```
>>> help(hasattr)
Help on built-in function hasattr in module __builtin__:

hasattr(...)
    hasattr(object, name) -> bool

    Return whether the object has an attribute with the given name.
    (This is done by calling getattr(object, name) and catching exceptions.)
```

For more advanced introspection read about the `inspect` module.

But first, tell us why you need this. There's a 99% chance that a better way exists...

Answer (score 1):

Python supports [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) - simply call the method on the instance.

Comment: It sounds like the OP doesn't know ahead of time what the parameters are - he wants to be able to query that information at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to align argument values with a function that has a unknown signature?

How will you match up argument values and parameter variables?  Guess?

You'd have to use some kind of name matching.

For example something like this.

```
someObject.someMethod( thisParam=aValue, thatParam=anotherValue )
```

Oh.  Wait.  That's already a first-class part of Python.

But what if the method doesn't exist (for inexplicable reasons).

```
try:
    someObject.someMethod( thisParam=aValue, thatParam=anotherValue )
except AttributeError:
    method doesn't exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test(object):
    def say_hello(name,msg = "Hello"):
        return name +' '+msg

def foo(obj,method_name):
    import inspect
    # dir gives info about attributes of an object
    if method_name in dir(obj):
        attr_info = eval('inspect.getargspec(obj.%s)'%method_name)
        # here you can implement logic to call the method
        # using attribute information
        return 'Done'
    else:
        return 'Method: %s not found for %s'%(method_name,obj.__str__)

if __name__=='__main__':    
    o1 = Test()
    print(foo(o1,'say_hello'))
    print(foo(o1,'say_bye'))
```

I think **`inspect`** module will be of very much help to you. 
Main functions used in above code are **`dir,eval,inspect.getargspec`**. You can get related help in python docs.

Comment: Using getattr(obj, method_name) is much cleaner than using eval.